# Indicate max hours per day per resource in MS Project Plan

Tags: ms-project, time-management, resource-planning

I have a project that has 4 team members in the plan:

- 2 developers @ 8 hours per day
- 2 developers @ 4 hours per day

How can I configure that two of those dev can only work 4 hours per day but the other two can work 8 hours per day?

**Also note**: all 4 can do work each day, so I can't simply combine the two 1/2-time devs into a 3rd full-time dev. I need the concurrency of tasks when I auto-schedule

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MS Project, first list down all your resources and their allocations. This can be done from **View > Resource Sheet** screen, for example like the screenshot given below:

[image: MS Project Resource Sheet]

Then assign tasks to the resources, for example:

[image: MS Project Tasks]

MS Project will automatically display that the resource is 50%.

Note that in the sample, Dev4 has been assigned 2 overlapping tasks. This means overallocation which is displayed in red color on the Resource Usage screen.

[image: MS Project Resource Usage]

I hope this will be of some help.

Comment: Thanks! In your example on Dev4 being overbooked, is that because you have manually assigned those tasks with those dates? If you were to make Task5 have Task4 as a predecessor and auto-schedule them it would auto-calculate the right dates, right? Thanks again!

Comment: @MarkUrsino yes, that is right. I manually assigned those tasks with those dates to Dev4 to demonstrate that MS Project shows Dev4 as "Over Allocated".